# Swap and Pop method solidty

Tags: solidity, transactions

Should I use swap and pop method in solidity, is there a chance of intercepting between these two events.(somebody adds an element after the swap is made, but before deletion)

```
uint lastIndex = array[index].length - 1;
bids[index][i] = array[index][lastIndex];
bids[rebelIndex].pop();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "intercept"? A transaction is either executed completely with changes persisted or it reversed with any change being dropped. Another contract cannot be executed in the middle (unless you explicitly call it).

Comment: What if between lines 2 and three a new element is added to the array using a separate transaction?

Comment: How would you execute a separate transaction in the middle? Transactions are executed in the order defined in the block. A transaction cannot be executed while another is still running.

Comment: Your questions have become my answers. Thank you!